# Run UWP on Android or iOS

Tags: xamarin, uwp

I want to add **finished UWP** app to **Xamarin Forms**. When i do that, can i run this **finished UWP app** on **Android** or **iOS** ? It will be best if you answer **"Yes"** or **"No"**. Have a nice day.

Comment: Neither "Yes" nor "No" will pass the answer quality filters.

Answer (score 6):

No, of course not.  UWP apps run on Windows, not Android/iOS.